# Calling a .net component from biztalk orchestration: Passing an XML message vs XML string?

Tags: biztalk

Does sending a message and then parsing in the .net component more memory efficient than sending a message.innerXML?

Answer (score 2):

So rather than try to retype this information, I believe that this link covers much of what your question is.

http://blogs.msdn.com/paolos/archive/2009/09/10/4-different-ways-to-process-an-xlangmessage-within-an-helper-component-invoked-by-an-orchestration.aspx

Answer (score 2):

check http://www.masteringbiztalk.com/blogs/jon/PermaLink,guid,e39cd386-0e62-46c6-87b6-3625f9a80d6d.aspx
that gives a nice walk thru of using an XLANGMessage inside of a .NET helper method.
importantly this article also mentions using XmlReader instead of XmlDocument for performance issues.
and even more importantly also highlights the needs to call Dispose() on the XLANGMessage before returning from your .NET helper method.

hope this helps

Comment: Just took the time too actually read that post - what a wealth of information, once one gets past the not so helpful orchestration diagrams. Thanks for the link.

Comment: that link is now dead

Comment: Found it in the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20080828015033/http://www.masteringbiztalk.com/blogs/jon/PermaLink,guid,e39cd386-0e62-46c6-87b6-3625f9a80d6d.aspx